# Log in with email but no password

Tags: login, email

I am designing a site that the client wants to only have members use their email to log in and no password.

Here is the old site and they want something like this. Is this possible with WordPress. I'm also using WP-Members plugin.

http://waiscon.com/planRoom.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could use `authenticate` filter for that. Below you can see how it's called:

```
$user = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);
```

So if you write your own filter which will select user only based on login/username, then it should work (maybe some other minor tweaks would be necessary).

PS. But I don't think you should do this. Authenticating users without passwords is rather big security problem. You also need to remember, that only some users should be authenticated this way (for example I'm pretty sure, that admin should still use password).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Krzysiek said this seems like a very bad idea unless you give your users virtually no capabilities aside from perhaps 'read' [more on roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). You should be able to do that easily using wp-members. If you allow them to do much more than that you are greatly increasing security risks.

You could also use something like `wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id)` to have certain users logged in automatically but again you would have to limit their capabilities to read or you would be opening the door to a huge security risk.